# How to limit rate of Actor executions within Actor-model?

Tags: java, concurrency, actor

There is a whole bucket of Actor model frameworks that focus on maximizing throughput of programmatically-defined.. erm.. actions (or should I say acts).

What implementations allow me to *put a limit* on the throughput, that is guarantee that a certain Actor does not get executed more than N times per minute? Another requirement is that the action must be carried out "as soon as possible" till the threshold is not exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the Actor Model the actor will only be executed when it has messages to process in the mailbox, you can use a throttling mechanism to limit how many times it is executed in a fraction of time. 
This blog post shows how it can be done with Akka: http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2

Comment: Thank you, this article is well detailed and the code has made its way to Akka 2.1, Java API has it in the package `akka.contrib.throttle`.
Meanwhile I have achieved similar solution in Java using synchronized queue and similar timer-based strategy, but my implementation is somewhat more simple, because it targets particular use-case where Actor's execution is synchronous (the poster of a message needs to know if the imposed action has been carried out).